# abort: No such file or directory: '/mnt/factotum/rpc' [Mercurial]

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-hook, mercurial-subrepos, mercurial-queue, mercurial-extension

I am having a problem in taking a clone, push or pull. When I do these, I get an error:

> abort: No such file or directory: '/mnt/factotum/rpc'

How can I resolve the issue?

- OS: Ubuntu 16
- Tool: Mercurial, BitBucket

Comment: Could you running the same command but adding the `--traceback` option so we would get a traceback to help you?

Comment: I tried all options but was unable to solve. I think this is related to user authorization.

Comment: A quickfix I did. I created a new user in ubuntu and used the new user and all worked fine.